# stringbuilder concatenations consuming more CPU and memory

Tags: .net, performance, stringbuilder

In a long running windows service written in c# uses Stringbuilder largely  for concatenations. In short span of time it needs to perform more concatenations. But it takes huge cpu and memory. Server has 16 GBRAM. Any solutions for this.?

Comment: You can allocate your stringbuilder with a capacity parameter to avoid the cost of continuously reallocating the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hard-and-fast rules, but there are different approaches.  Try reviewing articles such as http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2012/08/12/performance-tips-system-text-stringbuilder-and-string-concat.aspx or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14936/StringBuilder-vs-String-Fast-String-Operations-wit for some ideas on how to approach this.